# Empty .csv file after python script export

Tags: python, export-to-csv

File is showing as being "modified" but remains 0kb and empty.

Using the following code:

```
import csv

from craigslist import CraigslistForSale
cl_f = CraigslistForSale (site = 'boston', area = 'gbs', category = 'sys', 
                      filters = {'min_price':5, 'max_price':300, 'has_image':True,
                                 'query':"by owner",'query':"imac"})

for result in cl_f.get_results(sort_by='newest',limit=5):
print result

with open('CL-iMac.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
```

Read through other "similar" questions but still unclear on how to resolve this.

e/print result after adding

```
for result in cl_f.get_results(sort_by='newest',limit=5):
    writer.writerow(result)
```

:

```
{'name': u'iMac Mid 2009', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-mid-2009/6504630631.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$190', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Bedford', 'id': u'6504630631', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 21:03'}
{'name': u'Apple - iMac Model A1311', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-model-a1311/6525426093.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$180', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'BOSTON', 'id': u'6525426093', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 19:57'}
{'name': u'Apple iMac 5.1 Model A1208 17" All-in-one', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-51-model-aall-in/6525156610.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$80', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'HYDE PARK', 'id': u'6525156610', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 13:43'}
{'name': u'imac computer 20 inch', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-computer-20-inch/6488426996.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$210', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Medford', 'id': u'6488426996', 'datetime': u'2018-03-08 11:17'}
{'name': u'Apple Magic Mouse & Keyboard Set', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-magic-mouse-keyboard-set/6521325579.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$80', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Malden', 'id': u'6521325579', 'datetime': u'2018-03-06 21:12'}

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Documents/Test.py", line 13, in <module>
writer.writerow(result)
Error: sequence expected
```

Comment: it has been modified because you opened it.. but then you closed it without writing anything to the file!

Comment: @johnashu Ok, how do I write the output to the file while it's open?

Answer (score 0):

The data is returned as dictionaries using a generator.

This will return each dictionary 1 at a time.

You want this to be in a list so you can iterate over it.

You will have to append each dictionary to a list.

```
#Create a list to hold the results.
data_parsed = []

#append each result to the list
for result in cl_f.get_results(sort_by='newest',limit=5):
    data_parsed.append(result)
```

Then you can write the data to csv as follows

```
with open('CL-iMac.csv', 'w') as f:
    #Create writer
    writer = csv.writer(f) 

    #Write header row from 1st item keys
    # name,has_image,url,has_map,price,geotag,where,id,datetime
    header = data_parsed[0].keys()
    writer.writerow(header)

    #Write each row from the values
    # iMac Mid 2009,True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-mid-2009/6504630631.html,True,$190,,Bedford,6504630631,2018-03-12 21:03

    for result in data_parsed:
        writer.writerow(result.values())
```

If i assume that

```
data_parsed = [{'name': u'iMac Mid 2009', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-mid-2009/6504630631.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$190', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Bedford', 'id': u'6504630631', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 21:03'},
{'name': u'Apple - iMac Model A1311', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-model-a1311/6525426093.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$180', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'BOSTON', 'id': u'6525426093', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 19:57'},
{'name': u'Apple iMac 5.1 Model A1208 17" All-in-one', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-51-model-aall-in/6525156610.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$80', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'HYDE PARK', 'id': u'6525156610', 'datetime': u'2018-03-12 13:43'},
{'name': u'imac computer 20 inch', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-computer-20-inch/6488426996.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$210', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Medford', 'id': u'6488426996', 'datetime': u'2018-03-08 11:17'},
{'name': u'Apple Magic Mouse & Keyboard Set', 'has_image': True, 'url': u'https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-magic-mouse-keyboard-set/6521325579.html', 'has_map': True, 'price': u'$80', 'geotag': None, 'where': u'Malden', 'id': u'6521325579', 'datetime': u'2018-03-06 21:12'}]
```

Then the above code creates the following csv data.

```
name,has_image,url,has_map,price,geotag,where,id,datetime
iMac Mid 2009,True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-mid-2009/6504630631.html,True,$190,,Bedford,6504630631,2018-03-12 21:03
Apple - iMac Model A1311,True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-model-a1311/6525426093.html,True,$180,,BOSTON,6525426093,2018-03-12 19:57
"Apple iMac 5.1 Model A1208 17"" All-in-one",True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-imac-51-model-aall-in/6525156610.html,True,$80,,HYDE PARK,6525156610,2018-03-12 13:43
imac computer 20 inch,True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/imac-computer-20-inch/6488426996.html,True,$210,,Medford,6488426996,2018-03-08 11:17
Apple Magic Mouse & Keyboard Set,True,https://boston.craigslist.org/gbs/sys/d/apple-magic-mouse-keyboard-set/6521325579.html,True,$80,,Malden,6521325579,2018-03-06 21:12
```

Comment: I have read the docs. The "data_to_write" is the output of the first section (import csv...print result) but I don't know how to point to it as the data to be written. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have edited my post.. I cannot get the Craigslist module to work with what i am using.. if that does not work can you post the result of `print result`

Comment: Still getting an error, unfortunately: 

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Documents/Test.py", line 13, in <module>
    writer.writerow(result)
    Error: sequence expected

also edited my initial question w/result of "print result"

Comment: Your latest update went completely over my head and looks completely different than any of the numerous search results I've read. 

How do I know if it's json data? Why do I need to "parse" it? Is there no easy way to "direct" the output of one portion of the code to be "exported" in a latter section of the code? 

I feel like this should be an easy and common ask.

Comment: Sorry.. I cannot use the craigslist module so i am guessing what the response will be...if  can you post the result of `print cl_f.get_results(sort_by='newest',limit=5)`. . I have updated using a guess that it is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: `print cl_f.get_results(sort_by='newest',limit=5)` displays the following: `<generator object get_results at 0x105044690>`

Comment: Cool.. in that case option 2 should work no problem.   Append to a list then write to csv..